# BIOS Supervisor Password just set but unrecognized as certain key characters are skipped

Tags: keyboard, bios, passwords

Just this morning I configured a BIOS Supervisor Password on my PC. (I left the User password unset.)
I subsequently needed to change something in boot settings.
I hit F2 on startup and am prompted to "Enter Supervisor or User Password"
I entered the password exactly as I had just set it. The field displays a string of * for each character.
I hit Enter.  Nothing happened. The same field is displayed now blank again.
I entered the password again.  Same thing. Field goes blank.
I entered it a third time and hit enter.
"Invalid Password"  and system shuts down.

I have been through this using several variations of the password.  (I even repeated it as if the Caps Lock had been on when I set it originally.)
Then I noticed that some characters did not cause a * to be displayed in the password field.
In fact it seems that only numbers and lower-case letters produce a *.
When I enter a upper-case letter, nothing is added to the string in the field.
This doesn't explain, however, why the Invalid Password message does not appear the first or second times I enter it.

Comment: Reset the supervisor password and do not use special characters. Your PC documentation for the BIOS will tell you. My own machine does not allow special characters when setting BIOS.

Comment: No special characters just numbers and upper-case and lower-case letters.
The upper-case letters don't seem to be entered when input  but the strange thing is that the initial entry receives no error. It seems to just reset the input field

Comment: Make sure no spaces in the password string.

Comment: Well I didn't hit the space bar when I entered or confirmed the password and I am not hitting it on entering the password now.
I will try later to authenticate by omitting the upper-case letters. (busy with other stuff now)